# Installing SVN separately after Apache (Windows)

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-xp, installation, xampp, tortoisesvn

My friends and I have recently began a final college project and we require the use of software version control system. I have used Subversion Tortoise and Silk when I was working as a web developer for a former employer and I thought it would be a good idea to use it.

Although I know how to install and run the client, I have no idea how to configure it to run as a server.

I am currently using an old Acer Aspire laptop running Windows XP as a web server. It already has (of course) Apache 2.2 and MySQL installed via XAMPP. How would I go to install TortoiseSVN so that it makes use of the web directory I made for Apache?

Should I start everything over considering I am using XAMPP or is there another way to do this? I do not mind formatting and perhaps migrating over to a Linux platform.

If I missed something or you need more details concerning my configuration, I'll edit this question.

Thank you in advance.

-Christopher

Answer (score 1):

Tortoise SVN is just an SVN client. You still need an SVN server. [Collabnet](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/) or [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) are the two most common. Collabnet is very easy to set up for Apache (never used Visual SVN). Just install the binaries and edit your `httpd.conf` to include the path to the DAV SVN plugins. Or, Collabnet include Apache for you if you want to run it on a different port or IP address.

Once you've got it set up and your repo's created, you then need to make sure your web server has an up to date copy. There are two common ways of doing this:

1. Do an `SVN checkout` into your public HTML folder. This will mean that all your `.svn` folders are present though and can cause a security risk. For internal use it should be OK though. Maintenance is easy cos then you can just do an SVN Update
2. Do an `SVN export` from your local working copy (after doing an SVN Update, of course) into your web server's Public HTML folder. This means that no `.svn` folders are lurking on the server.

Comment: I'll give it a try and tell you how it goes. For now I'll just give you a +1 :)